# Como puedo guardar un formulario usando codigo C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda en el lenguaje C# 
cree un formulario con el código de form a= new form(); a.show(); 
y quiero guardar ese formulario en el proyecto ya que solo con ese código se abre el formulario pero no se guarda en el proyecto ¿Existe alguna forma de poder guardar ese formulario en el proyecto?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres... Te pasas por [mcve] y luego nos detallas tu problema? ¡Ah! Si te pasas por el [tour] aprenderas el funcionamiento del sitio y ganas tu primer medalla!

Comment: Y eso por que lo quieres hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes dos o más formularios, necesita de un objeto para almacenar la información, dado que al pasar de un formulario a otro, estas instanciando un nuevo formulario (En otras palabras, empiezas de nuevo), por lo tanto puedes seguir este ejemplo.

Estructura de la persona (DTO):

```
public class Persona
{
    public string Nombre {get; set;}

    public Persona(){}
}
```

Formulario Principal, la cual comienza la aplicación

```
public class FormularioPrincipal
{   
    public Persona Persona = null;

    public void AbrirFormulario2()
    {
        Persona persona = new Persona();
        Persona = persona;
        FormularioPersona form = new FormularioPersona(ref persona);
        this.Hide();
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Formulario la cual se llena toda la información de la persona (Vista)

```
public class FormularioPersona
{
    public Persona Persona = null;

    /*Constructor del formulario, la cual hace referencia al objeto persona del formulario principal*/
    public FormularioPersona (ref persona)
    {
        Persona = persona;
    }

    /*Método para completar la informacción de una persona*/
    public void CompletarInformacionPersona()
    {
        Persona.Nombre = textbox.Text;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Saludos, espero haberte ayudado.